# Is bracket notation slower than period notation for accessing Object properties?

Tags: javascript, performance, object, brackets, notation

A developer on my team mentioned that accessing an Object property via dot notation is faster than bracket notation. For example:

```
var sample = { name: 'First Name' }
var nameBracket = sample['name']
var namePeriod = sample.name
```

In this case, their belief was that the assignment of `namePeriod` would be faster than `nameBracket`.

Is this true? If so, why? If not, why not?

Related: How would one test this hypothesis or a similar question to determine JS function speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to try to test speeds of different approaches, it seems the defacto tool is jsperf.com.

Someone has already questioned this, and created a test for it.

http://jsperf.com/dot-notation-vs-square-bracket-notation

The results seem to be about the same. What causes slowdows is when the contents of the bracket are a variable - at that point the compiler can no longer say to itself "Oh, ['foo'] is the same as .foo.. continuing on!".

Comment: Or when the contents are any other expression that isn't just a string, `obj[function(){ for( var start = (new Date).getTime(); (new Date).getTime() < start + 10000; ); return 'foo';}()]` will take about 10 seconds longer than `obj.foo` :P

Comment: Oh you know what I meant :P